# How to implement bidirectional foreign key with ecto

Tags: elixir, ecto

I am new with elixir programming and I am trying to migrate two databases with a foreign key in both tables but it doesn’t seem to work ??

```
def change do
  create table(:users) do
    add :username, :string
    add :email, :string
    add :name, :string
    add :password, :string
    add :address, :string


    timestamps()
  end

  alter table("users") do
    add :organization, references(:organization)
  end

end

def change do
  create table(:organization) do
    add :org_key, :string
    add :name, :string

    timestamps()
  end

  create unique_index(:organization, [:org_key])

  alter table("organization") do
    add :creator, references(:users)
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes, that would probably fail because each one requires the other. You could probably create the users table without references, then create the `organizations` table with the reference to users, and then alter `users` to add the reference to `organizations`. Because the tables need to exist when referencing them

Comment: Why don't you create two relationship tables? For example, one is `user_organization` to save the users of an organization and the other `organization_creators` to save the organization creators ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear why/whatfor do you have two different migrations, but as @sbacarob said in comments, one surely cannot reference inexisting yet table `:organizations` from the former.

There is no magic, the code gets executed line by line and one cannot reference something before the declaration. The following would most likely work.

```elixir
def change do
  create table(:users) do
    …
  end

  create table(:organizations) do
    …
  end

  create unique_index(:organizations, [:org_key])

  alter table("organizations") do
    add :creator, references(:users)
  end

  alter table("users") do
    add :organization, references(:organizations)
  end
end
```